# Multidimensional array index to row,col,depth values?

Tags: c, math

I have a few values which are offsets to a multidimensional array , and look like this :

```
static const int TILE_SIZE = 32;
int Offset2D = (y * TILE_SIZE) + (x * TILE_SIZE);
int Offset3D = (y * TILE_SIZE) + (x * TILE_SIZE) + (z * TILE_SIZE);
```

Now what i would like to do is to convert an offset to x,y,z pair , like so :

```
void ConvertBack(int offset,int size,int& x,int& y,int& z)
{
    //What's wrong with this code ?
    x = offset / size;
    y = offset % size;
    z = ??; //How to get Z?
}
```

or

```
//Get back offsets from any dimension ?

void ConvertBackComplex(unsigned int offset,int size,int* vector,int len)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < len;i++)
    {
        vector[i] = offset ?... ?
    }
}
```

...So far all of my attempts have failed....So i would really welcome any help!...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I think you indexing system is a bit off. The way you have things arranged different values of x, y, and z can give the same offset. So, first of all, assuming that TILE_SIZE is how many cells of the array store the data for a given point:

```
myArray = new arr[xSize*ySize*zSize*TILESIZE]
int offset2D = (x*ySize*zSize + y*zSize)*TILE_SIZE;
int offset3D = (x*ySize*zSize + y*zSize + z)*TILE_SIZE;
```

To get x,y,z back from the offset one simply does the following:

```
temp = offset/TILE_SIZE;
x = temp/(ySize*zSize);
y = (temp%(ySize*zSize))/zSize;
z = (temp%(ySize*zSize))%zSize;
```

For multiple dimensions:

```
temp = offset/TILE_SIZE;
sizeProduct = 1;
for(int k=1; k<numDims; ++k)
{
    sizeProduct*=size[k];
}
for(int i=0; i<numDims; ++i)
{
    vector[i]=temp/sizeProduct;
    temp = temp % sizeProduct;
    if((i+1)<numDims)
    {
        sizeProduct/=sizes[i+1];
    }
}
```

To calculate array sizes in multiple dimensions:

```
int arraySize = TILE_SIZE;
for(int i=0; i<numDims; ++i)
{
    arraySize*=sizes[i];
}
```

To calculate array indices in multiple dimensions (assuming vector is your array of coordinates):

```
int index =0;
sizeProduct = 1;
for(int k=1; k<numDims; ++k)
{
    sizeProduct*=size[k];
}
for(int i=0; i<numDims; ++i)
{
    index+=sizeProduct*vector[i];
    if((i+1)<numDims)
    {
        sizeProduct/=sizes[i+1];
    }
}
index*=TILE_SIZE;
```

Comment: Very nice!But im just a little curious about the multi dim reverse function version .... how would i calculate the length of the array and the index  (hope im not asking much :p)?

Comment: I am now adding that to my answer.

Comment: Sorry if it was more general than you wanted. I used arbitrary sizes for each of the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all dimensions are `TILE_SIZE` long, your offset calculations are wrong. Let's say I have an array `a` which simulated 3d array with all dimensions `TILE_SIZE` long:

```
int a[TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE];
```

Then point `p` with coordinates `(x, y, z)` would have an offset like this:

```
int p_offset = z * (TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE)
             + y * (TILE_SIZE)
             + x;
```

Reverse calculation is then:

```
int p_z = p_offset / (TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE);
int p_y = (p_offset - p_z * (TILE_SIZE * TILE_SIZE)) / TILE_SIZE;
int p_x = p_offset % TILE_SIZE;
```

You can choose different order of dimensions `(x, y, z)` but you have to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dimensions go from X to Y to Z (as in X represents the lowest dimension):

You can't use a single function to calculate both the 2D and 3D offsets back into coordinates.

For 2D:

```
void ConvertBack2D(int offset, int x_len, int &x, int &y)
{
    y = offset / x_len;
    x = offset % x_len;
}
```

For 3D:

```
void ConvertBack3D(int offset, int x_len, int y_len, int &x, int &y, int &z)
{
    z = offset / (x_len * y_len);
    y = (offset - (x * x_len * y_len)) / y_len;
    x = (offset - (x * x_len * y_len)) % x_len;
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy to understand versions as well!Thanks for the input!